How do I call a Rascal function from Rust
I am working on a Rust CLI (using Clap) to use along side my Rascal DSL by problem is this. How do I call a Rascal function (functions defined my DSL) in my Rust CLI code? I have previously implemented this CLI in Python (using Click) and implemented the inter-ops between Rascal and Python using JPype but the performance was horrendous. I hope to improve the performance by rewriting my CLI in Rust but I am not sure how to implement the inter-ops between Rascal and Rust. I will be glad if someone could help me out.

There's a current PR open that ports our REPL code to jline3. This also includes util::TermREPL with which it is easy to make DSL repls. Also have a look at the bacata rascal library that you can use to instantiate notebooks for DSLs. All based on the REPL protocol. By @mauricioverano

I think the best way for fast results and reasonable performance is to use rascal's built-in web application server in util::Webserver of the standard library.

Use lang::json::IO for fast and convenient mappings between json values and Rascal values.
The server can stream json directly.
Connect the rust program via synchronous or asynchronous http requests and use a Rust library for binding JSON values.
Use LOC values to identify things consistently between client and server, like qualified names in your DSL and source files.

This is basically the way the LSP services work as well. We're planning to add web sockets to util::Webserver later. The standard library has examples in vis::Charts and vis::Graphs where JSON is used to communicate with JavaScript libraries on the other side. The "DrAmbiguity" project is a much bigger example that's built on top of the "salix" UI framework, but farther from your usecase. Those vis examples simply transform rascal values to json and communicate them over http via util::WebServer.
Tip: if a Rascal web service (of type Content is returned on the REPL it will be served automatically and its index page shown in your browser without having to start a server yourself with util::WebServer. Good for testing and debugging; saves time and you always know your looking at the latest version.
An alternative, more creative, route is to use the language parametric LSP servers; using the rascal-lsp library you can spin up LSP servers and load your Rascal service implementations in there. The main module to use is util::LanguageServer. If your functionality falls within the protocol then you can develop and test it within VScode and connect it to a Rust or C based LSP client.
Finally you could copy the design of `util::TermRepl‘ and replace the java side of it by a JNI implementation that connects to the rust REPL.
I'd go for the first because you'd have that up and running in no time.

Thanks I have pretty much got everything working but I don't know how to implement Json streaming with the Rascal web application server.

Hi. You can use the jsonResponse constructor from  the Content module. You can pass it any value and that value will be streamed as JSON using the same algorithm as you can access from lang::json::IO.

Thanks for your response it took me a while to respond because I am still trying to fully understand the implementation you suggested.
My understanding is that:

I need to run a server on the Rust client (CLI) that would take user commands and convert it to a JSON payload to be sent to the Rascal backend
I need to also run a server on the Rascal backend that would accept request from the client, marshal the payload sent by the client into a Rascal ADT
and use it to call a Rascal function then convert the result into a JSON payload to be sent back to the server.

I assume this setup would work for any client app (Java, Python etc). I will look at the util::Webserver api to see how to spawn a server in Rascal if there are
any examples I will be extremely glad if you can point me to it. I already have some experience working with lang::json::IO.
Thanks once again this is very useful.

Benni your question should go in a comment not an answer to your own question. I'd remove this answer for better appreciation of your contribution to so.

I will add a reference you an example in my answer

I actually tried that first but I got an error message that it was 302 characters too long
